# I'm looking for feedback and some clarifcation on the shahada tag!

Tags: discussion, tag, tag-mistakes

I have a question in mind on the topic of martyr and tried to find an appropriate tag as I'm primarily thinking in Arabic my first thought was to look for shahadah [الشهادة](https://www.almaany.com/en/dict/ar-en/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D9%87%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%A9/), which has different meanings in Arabic:

- a testimony (in context of juristic matters etc.)
- a certificate (diploma etc.)
- the declaration of faith in Islam is falsely called a-Shahadah while in Arabic it is actually a-Shaadatan الشهادتان or a-Shahadatayn الشهادتين depending on the grammatical context (See also [Is there a specific sequence of Arabic words which is considered "the shahada"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37275/is-there-a-specific-sequence-of-arabic-words-which-is-considered-the-shahada)).
- and martyrdom.

From the above perspective using the tag [shahadah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shahadah) exactly for the declaration of faith is wrong, but I suppose that this is rather the first thing non-Arabic Muslims would think of when hearing or reading this term.

Therefore and first I would like to have some feedback about the thoughts I've shared with you above.
And secondly would like to know if you agree to change the tag wiki as the last paragraph (see quote below) is simply wrong even if non-Arabic Muslims may think of shahadat (referring to martyrdom) as a different word than shahadah (referring to the testimony or declaration of faith).

> ash-Shahada الشهادة or the two shadaat الشهادتان is an Islamic creed declaring belief in oneness of God and the acceptance of Muhammad as God's prophet.
>
> The Declaration in it's shortest form is: (Arabic) لا إله إلا الله محمد رسول الله (Transliteration) lā ʾilāha ʾillā-llāh, muḥammadur-rasūlu-llāh (English-Translation) There is no god but God. Muhammad is the messenger of God
>
> One should clearly distinguish ash-Shahada as a creed which is a testimony and the first of five Pillars of Islam (for Sunni Muslims) with ash-Shahadat as the death as Martyr

IMHO also the provided shortest form actually is not a valid shahadah but a statement and might be replaced by: أشهد أن لا إله إلا الله وأنّ محمدا رسول الله

My suggestions for a change is either deleting the last paragraph or replacing/adding it by:

> ash-Shahada الشهادة or *more exactly* the two shadaat الشهادتان is an Islamic creed declaring belief in oneness of God and the acceptance of Muhammad as God's prophet.
>
> The Declaration in it's shortest form is: (Arabic) *أشهد أن* لا إله إلا الله وأنّ *محمدا* رسول الله (Transliteration) *Ashhadu an* lā ʾilāha ʾillā-llāh, *wa anna* muḥammad*an*-rasūlu-llāh (English-Translation) *I testify that* there is no god but God. And Muhammad is the messenger of God
>
> *We clearly* distinguish ash-Shahada as a creed which is a testimony and the first of five Pillars of Islam (for Sunni Muslims) with ash-Shahadat *-in Arabic also الشهادة- which refers to* the death as Martyr. *Please use the tag  [martyr](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/martyr) for martyrdom.*